# IntelliJ idea vim plugin edit auto insert mode

Tags: intellij-idea, vim-plugin, ideavim

ideaVim plugin automatically flips from `Normal Mode` to `Insert mode` for the following scenario:

- Mistaken key strokes. (This was the single reason I loved vim plugin, because I needn't  worry about changing my code mistakenly.)

I tried playing around with ~/.ideaVim file to see if this feature can be removed. I loved the earlier version.

Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: Can you clarify what mistaken keystrokes you're talking about? Maybe also describe what old behavior you liked and what new behavior you don't like? As written it's not clear to me what you're asking...

Comment: @jbyler if I type any keys while in `Normal Mode` the ideaVim plugin automatically flips to `Insert Mode`. This was not the case earlier. I am talking about intellij v12

Comment: Normal mode is for entering commands.  The keystrokes are not ignored but are interpreted as commands.  The `i` command enters insert mode, so if you mistakenly type `i` while in normal mode, you will enter insert mode.  Similarly, many other commands leave you in insert mode, e.g. `cw` for change word, `C` for change line, etc.  But other keystrokes—e.g. `j` for down and `k` for up—will not enter insert mode.  Does that explain the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that.